# Why is @googlemaps/js-api-loader's Autocomplete data not passed on to data object with a v-model binding?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

My Vue CLI project uses the Google Maps API to process locations from user input. The loader is imported as follows:

```
import { Loader } from "@googlemaps/js-api-loader";
```

And, this is how it is instantiated:

```
const loader = new Loader({
  apiKey: "XXXXX",
  version: "weekly",
  libraries: ["places"]
});
```

I have a text input element that accepts a location from the user:

```
<input type="text" v-model="origin" id="origin" placeholder="Where are you?" />
```

It uses the Google Maps API's Autocomplete class to suggest or auto complete addresses (the code is sitting in the created object/option of the Vue instance):

```
loader
  .load()
  .then(() => {
    new window.google.maps.places.Autocomplete(
      document.getElementById("origin"),
      {
        componentRestrictions: { country: "za" },
        fields: ["address_components", "geometry", "icon", "name"],
      }
    );
  });
```

Now, let's say I want to enter the address "123 Mandela Street, Some Suburb, 2021" and I type "123 Ma" then click on the auto completed address, data.origin will only have "123 Ma" and not the full address. Where am I going wrong?

Comment: After reading the Places Autocomplete guide again, I found a workaround. I removed the binding and added the a listener for the place_changed event and I am sorted. At least for now. It would still be interesting to know why the data is not passed on to the data object though.

Answer (score 3):

According to the documentation [here](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/places-autocomplete#summary-of-classes), `Autocomplete` adds a text input field to your web page, and monitors that field for character entries. So, whatever the user types into your text input field remains that and the only data passed on to the data object on bind.

Adding a handler for the `place_changed` event and the `formatted_address` field in the options is the practical way to go about retrieving the address chosen/added by the user.